# How to analyze httpd (apache webserver) logs in CentOS 7

Tags: apache, logging, analyzer, centos7, nanohttpd

I have configred a static IP on my server that is using CentOS 7. Here httpd is the webserver. Now I have to analyze following things.

1. Total number of queries per day (or toall)
2. Total requests sent and served.
3. Unique visitors details
4. List of queries recieved. (status etc.)
5. HOSTs/OS/Browsers that request for query
6. Errors etc.
7. Should be able to save it in CSV etc. format so that I can import it to excel.

Can anyone suggest me some log analyzer that will fullfill above requirements ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [goaccess](http://goaccess.io) will fulfill your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

[Splunk](http://splunk.com) has a [tutorial](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchTutorial/Startsearching) almost about the same as you are asking. The downside that it is a commercial program (free up to 500 MB of data per day).

Otherwise have a look at the [ELK stack](https://www.elastic.co/products), combining Elastic (to index the data), Logstash (to get them into Elastic) and Kibana (to display them) should [fit your list](http://www.hackzine.org/importing-apache-logs-in-elasticsearch.html).